# Right click doesn't work on HP mini 210 touchpad

Tags: 10.10, hardware, ubuntu-netbook, touchpad, hp

Need help in getting the right mouse click to work on a HP mini 210-1015TU when using the touchpad.

If I plug in a USB mouse, both left click and right click function as normal. Using the touchpad however I can only get the left click to work. Attempting to right click gives the result expected from a left click. As per some comments on a forum I added a file `11-touchpad.conf` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. I can provide further details if required.

This made touchpad operation noticeably smoother but the problem with the right mouse click remains. Not a hardware problem as right clicked worked with 10.04 and still works with Windows 7 starter.  10.10 installed using wubi.

Comment: It would help if you would describe a little more what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: If I plug in a USB mouse, both left click and right click function as normal.  Using the touchpad however I can only get the left click to work.  Attempting to right click gives the result expected from a left click.  As per some comments on a forum I added a file 11-touchpad.conf to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d.  I can provide further details if required. This made touchpad operation noticeably smoother but the problem with the right mouse click remains

Comment: Has the right button always worked until now?  If you have never seen it work, maybe the button is physically broken.

Comment: Yes, right mouse button worked on 10.04 and still works on Windows 7 starter (I installed 10.10 using Wubi)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Touchpad not working on HP Pavilion dv6](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6523/touchpad-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dv6)

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in installing [gpointing-device-settings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings) 
package, which will provide more configuration options for your touchpad.

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

Once installed you find it under **System -> Preferences -> Pointing Devices**.

Comment: This worked a treat for me too - many thanks!
(On a HP Mini 210-2001sa - fresh install of Netbook 10.10)

Answer (score 3):

is that i'm going to input:

`sudo su`
(Enter your password)

```
echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe
reboot
```

p/s: since i'm a newbie, i need to confirm the command to solve my problem at hp mini 210-1073TU.

Comment: That worked for me.

Comment: Pretty awesome! Working fine as a solution for the HP Pavilion dm4. Solved my issue! Thank you!

Comment: I own a hp elite-book 8530w. The modprobe.d fix didn't do it for me. Just led to mentioned lack of scrolling and sensibilty reduction. Anyone has an idea for me?

Answer (score 1):

try TAPPING the lower right corner of the touchpad instead of clicking the button

Comment: Occasionally this does work, but in most cases it responds as a left click.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround which worked with my **Lenovo Edge E320** with a clickpad.

Just create `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51.clickpad.conf` and paste the following content:

```
Section "InputClass" 

Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics" 
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"

EndSection
```

After a restart of the `xserver` the clickpad worked just fine and the mulitouch features are now operational.

Source: [Ubuntuusers.de](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kein-rechtsclick-mit-hp-clickpad-moeglich-dv7-/)

Answer (score 0):

Just create `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51.clickpad.conf` and paste the following content:

```
Section "InputClass" 
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics" 
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection*
```

This works great on an HP pavilion 15 p132nd, for anyone experiencing a rightclick problem on this system. After adding the new file and the lines as in the post, just restart the system to make it work.