# Can't right click on an HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, hp-pavilion, dv6

After installing, I initially assumed that right-clicking just wasn't a feature.  I've been trying to separate myself from what I'm accustomed to in Windows, so I didn't think much of it.  I've since read that right-clicking is definitely something other people are able to do.

However, right-clicks, in any context, are behaving as left-clicks.  I'm using the touch-pad on an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop.  Did something go wrong with my installation?  Maybe a driver issue?  I've tried quite a few Google searches on the issue, and I haven't come up with any results relating to a complete loss of right-mouse functionality.

I have read that Shift+F10 is the default keyboard shortcut for right-clicking.  However, I am finding that it has no noticeable effect whatsoever when used.

I've checked System Settings, and I don't see anything that allows for toggling the right touch-pad button on or off.  Lacking experience with the system, I don't really know where to look next.

My questions then, would be:

- Am I crazy, or does 12.04 normally have a right-click function that brings up a menu pane?
- Is this a problem that anyone has heard of or encountered previously?
- If so, how has it been resolved in the past?
- My buttons are indeed part of a click-pad.

I checked some of the "related" links that showed up with the page.  I checked 
`synclient -l` and found that quite a few parameters were questionably set at 0.

```
 RightButtonAreaLeft = 0
 RightButtonAreaRight = 0
 RightButtonAreaTop = 0
 RightButtonAreaBottom = 0
```

The same goes for the MiddleButtonX parameters, but I'm not concerned about those.

```
ClickPad = 1
```

All of the AreaXEdge parameters = 0
At the top of the list, these four parameters stand out:

```
LeftEdge = 1766
RightEdge = 5378
TopEdge = 1627
BottomEdge = 4331
```

I haven't tried to adjust these before.  I imagine that it could easily vary a great deal between click-pad models, but does anyone know which of the above parameters I actually want to adjust, and to what values?

Comment: Do you have an external mouse you can test with? It might be a touchpad issue.

Comment: I don't have one immediately available, I'm afraid.  Also, did I have correct information on Shift+F10 functioning as a right-click shortcut?  Because I assume that the keyboard shortcut should operate independently of my click-pad settings.

Comment: Shift-10 is correct.

Comment: So, if the shortcut doesn't work either, does that point to a different issue, or perhaps better explain the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what the original problem was, and I'm not entirely sure how my pad is mapped.

That said, I found an interesting work-around here:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_TouchPads_.28aka_ClickPads.29

It mentioned changing some options within `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf`, but that directory doesn't seem to exist for me.  It suggested changing certain values for the *percentage* of the click-pad to be dedicated to a given button, and then it suggested checking certain parameters within `synclient -l`.  I wound up just manually editing the parameters to match.  The boundaries do not seem to match perfectly with the lines marked on my click-pad, but those are completely arbitrary.  The differences could be resolved by trial and error if it became an issue, I suppose.

Shift+F10 still does not work, but I have since learned that right-click was simply mapped elsewhere.  I don't know where to find the default settings for that particular shortcut; it is not included in the list shown by holding down Super.  However, I have learned that it was mapped by default to a button between my right alt and ctrl keys.  The key resembles the usual menu, with one bar highlighted.  This probably won't be relevant to many folks on non-HP machines.

Thanks, everyone, for taking the time to work with me.

Comment: ok one more thing, just mark your answer as the accepted one so it shows up at the top, thanks for sharing your information!

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow," says the orange box.  I'll get on that once I receive permission.  Thanks for the beta, Jorge!  This has been a good first experience with the community built up around Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP Pavilion dv7 and I notice that when all the `RightButtonArea[Top/Bottom/Left/Right]` parameters are 0, my right mouse button doesn't work (or more accurately it behaves the same as the left button).  This recently started (perhaps when I installed ccsm).  This is fixed for me by the following terminal commands `synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=3572` and `synclient RightButtonAreaTop=3984` (which were the defaults when I first installed 12.04).  For some reason, putting these values in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` *and* `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` isn't making the changes permanent on my system.  I had to make a simple script with the above `synclient` commands in it that runs at system startup.  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26290/50-synaptics-conf-options-not-working) has a lot of info but nothing worked for me except a startup script.

Comment: Hi!  Sorry I'm late in replying, but I'm glad you found a work around.  Although I am a bit less detailed in my description, this is the solution given in the page linked in the chosen answer.  I found a start-up script to be very useful as well.  That said, I haven't had this problem in any of my reinstalls of Precise on the same machine, the first of which was sometime in the spring of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have "real" buttons or is it a click-pad? In the case of my Asus UX-31 with an Elan Clickpad I had to enable right-click functionality by a workaround. 
Let me assure you that Linux **does** know the concept of right clicking.

I don't know if this will help you with your hp but have a look at this link: 
http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/02/call-for-testing-clickpad.html

Comment: It's a click-pad.  I apologize, but your link went a bit over my current level of comprehension.

Comment: You have to enter the various commands in that page in a terminal window which you can open by pressing CTRL + ALT + T.

Comment: Yes, if you're not familiar with working in a terminal, this might look complicated. But it's easier than it looks. What do you want explained in particular?

Comment: Maybe wait to see if someone with this notebook notices this question first and can offer a simpler solution? Testing PPAs for new users might be asking for trouble. (A simple solution might not exist, but maybe we'll get lucky with a simple config instead of a testing PPA)

Comment: I'm aware of the terminal.  I meant they were over my head insofar as I wasn't sure to what extent they would address my issue.  I'm just trying to be careful before I go throwing things into the terminal as root, since I have no idea what I'm doing.  Would manually editing the values of the above parameters (see edited post) be a potential solution?  Thanks for all the support so far, by the way.

Comment: You're perfectly right to be cautious about blindly copy-pasting  commands. And I totally agree with Jorge Castro. Having someone explain it who has the same hardware at hand would be best. The PPA worked, as I said, like a charm with my Elantech Clickpad. You are right about Shift+F10, by the way.

Comment: I've found several older questions using my HP model, but the users were running 11.10 and 10.10.  Their click-pad problems also seem to have been slightly different.  Not sure how relevant the solutions are.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/6523/touchpad-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dv6?rq=1  http://askubuntu.com/questions/83590/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-using-the-upper-left-corner-on-an-hp-pavilion-dv6?rq=1  I'll add some of my hardware info as tags.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what the original problem was, and I'm not entirely sure how my pad is mapped.

That said, I found an interesting work-around here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_TouchPads_.28aka_ClickPads.29

It mentioned changing some options within `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf`, but that directory doesn't seem to exist for me.  It suggested changing certain values for the *percentage* of the click-pad to be dedicated to a given button, and then it suggested checking certain parameters within `synclient -l`.

Comment: I wound up just manually editing the parameters to match.  The boundaries do not seem to match perfectly with the lines marked on my click-pad, but those are completely arbitrary.  The differences could be resolved by trial and error if it became an issue, I suppose.

Shift+F10 still does not work, but I am quite happy to now have a functional click-pad.  Thanks, everyone, for taking the time to work with me.

(I would have posted this all as an answer, but I am not able to do so for 6 hours due to my status as a new user.)

Comment: @Ben it would be great if you could post all this as a new answer so other owners of the dv6 can have clear instructions on how to solve the problem, thanks!